# What is meant here by "element of the prime field corresponding to $a \in \mathbb{Z}$"?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, finite-fields, extension-field, groups-of-lie-type

I'm reading about the construction of Chevalley groups over an arbitrary field K.

Carter originally introduces an automorphism on the Chevalley basis $\{h_r,r \in \Pi; \quad e_r, r \in \Phi \}$ and then 'extends' it to act on $\{1_K \otimes h_r , r \in \Pi; 1_K \otimes e_r, r \in \Phi \}$.

He then mentions that when just acting on the normal Chevalley basis, for fixed $r \in \Phi$ we can represent $x_r(\zeta) = \text{exp}(\zeta\text{ad}_{e_r})$ by a matrix with elements of the form $a \zeta^i$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $i \geq 0$.

He says the automorphism that acts on the extended Chevalley basis can also be represented by a matrix for fixed root with entries of the form:
 $\bar{a}t^i$ where $t \in K$ and $\bar{a} \textbf{ is the element of the prime field of } K \textbf{ corresponding to }a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What exactly is meant by this? Am I right in thinking that this is just $1_K \otimes a$?

Comment: Prime subfield is the unique smallest subfield of $K$. It seems that $\overline{a}$ is simply $a\cdot 1_K$. If that makes sense.

Comment: If the field is finite then its order is a power of its characteristic which must be prime... so am I right in thinking that the prime subfield is just going to be the subfield which has a prime number of elements (equal to its characteristic)? If so then this makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: If $K$ is of characteristic $0$ then the prime subfield is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. If $K$ is of characteristic $p>0$ then yes, the prime subfield is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There is a unique commutative unitial ring morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to the field $K$. They are talking about the image of an element under that morphism.